# static IP configuration

Tags: static-ip

I'm using strech version on Rasp and I'm facing difficulties to configure my wlan0 with a static IP address.

I have 2 wlan, one is onboard (wlan0) and another one is a USB device (wlan1). I disabled onboard and stayed with USB one. So after rebooting wlan0 is assigned to USB wlan device.

Now, according to several questions posted here, I changed the /etc/dhcpcd.conf file and added the following lines

```
ipv4only  
profile static_wlan0
interface wlan0
static ip_address=192.168.10.2/24
static routers=192.168.10.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.10.1 8.8.8.8
interface wlan0
fallback static_wlan0
```

What happens is: if the wlan is not connected to an access point, there is no static IP address configured. If it is connected to an access point, then the static IP is configured.

So, the point is: I want to understand how dhcpd behaves and how can I have a static IP address without connecting to an Access Point ?

Comment: What is the point of having an IP address on an interface which is not connected?

Comment: An IP is something given to a device when its connected to a network so other devices can find it to connect to it. Like a home address is used to make sure your post gets to you. If the device is not connected to a network it wont have an IP address. Each network will have a DHCP server (usually part of the router) which will issue an IP address to each device connected which will allow them to talk to each other. A static IP is simply an IP you specify so the device will always have the same IP (useful for things NAS setups). Why do want a static IP whilst not connected to a network??